# Print into a terminal's "scrollback buffer"?

Tags: terminal, overwrite

Many terminal applications have a "scrollback buffer", rather than just the currently-viewed terminal window. Is there some common (or even standard) mechanism for a process to print into that buffer, partially overwriting previous contents?

For example, if my scrollback buffer is:

```
a first line
the quick           jumped over the lazy dog
a third line
```

and I launch my process, can I somehow have it "print brown fox starting at the second line from the end of the buffer, at character 10", and get

```
a first line
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
a third line
```

?

Note: If this is possible only for some specific apps, that would also be relevant.